# What is this script use for?

Tags: bash, scripting

```
for m in {1..100}
    do
        r1=`shuf -n1 -i1-100`
        r2=`shuf -n1 -i1-100`
        if [[ "${r1}" -lt "${r2}" ]]
        then
            resstr=`echo "$m" | md5sum | cut -b ${r1}-${r2}`
        else
            resstr=`echo "$m" | md5sum | cut -b ${r2}-${r1}`
        fi
        str="."
        for n in `echo ${resstr}|fold -w1`
        do
          str="${str}/`shuf -n5 -i100-500| tr -d '\n'|md5sum |cut -b1-6`"
        done
        echo "mkdir -p ${str}"
    done
```

I tried to run it locally but ran into errors. Can someone explain what this does and how is this useful please?

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: this script is very pointless it isn't just homework ?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023571/what-is-this-script-supposed-to-do

Answer (score 1):

The script, which assumes `bash` or some other shell that does brace expansions, and that GNU coreutils is installed, outputs `mkdir` commands for creating some sort of directory structure where there directories have names from MD5 checksums calculated on random numbers.

Whether this is useful or not, I don't know. There's no immediate error in the script except for a few style issues and unquoted variable expansions.